# NestJS - add dependencies as interface

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

The way we add dependencies in NestJS is by using the `@Injectable` annotation:

```
export class ConversationService {
  constructor(
    @Injectable() private userService: UserService,
    @Injectable() private cacheService: CacheService,
    @Injectable() private emailService: EmailService,
  ) {}
}
```

Do you know if there is a way to add dependencies like an interface of injectables? I couldn't find anything like that in the docs:

```
interface ConversationServiceDependencies {
  userService: UserService;
  cacheService: CacheService;
  emailService: EmailService;
}

export class ConversationService {
  constructor(
    @Injectable() private dependencies: ConversationServiceDependencies,
  ) {}
}
```

Thank y'all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `@Injectable()` should be in the class. And you'll have to define some token in `@Inject()`, like so:

```js
@Injectable() // not needed in this case
export class ConversationService {
  constructor(
    @Inject('ConversationServiceDependencies') private dependencies: ConversationServiceDependencies,
  ) {}
}
```

because interfaces didn't exists at runtime *(a typescript thing)*.

and then you'll need to define what's the value of that provider at your nestjs module. This is covered in the docs btw.

Or you could use this lib: [`nestjs-injectable`](https://github.com/segmentstream/nestjs-injectable)